# Is `function-definition` a `declaration`?

Tags: c, function, declaration

In the C11 standard

> 6.9  External definitions
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> translation-unit:
> external-declaration
> translation-unit  external-declaration
>
> external-declaration:
> function-definition
> declaration
> ```

where

> 6.9.1  Function definitions
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> function-definition:
> declaration-specifiers declarator  declaration-listopt compound-statement
>
> declaration-list:
> declaration
> declaration-list  declaration
> ```

and

> 6.7  Declarations
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> declaration:
> declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
> static_assert-declaration
>
> declaration-specifiers:
> storage-class-specifier  declaration-specifiersopt
> type-specifier  declaration-specifiersopt
> type-qualifier  declaration-specifiersopt
> function-specifier  declaration-specifiersopt
> alignment-specifier  declaration-specifiersopt
>
> init-declarator-list:
> init-declarator
> init-declarator-list , init-declarator
>
> init-declarator:
> declarator
> declarator = initializer
> ```
>
> ...
>
> A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of
> identifiers. A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that
> identifier that:
>
> - for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
> - **for a function, includes the function body;**
> - for an enumeration constant, is the (only) declaration of the identifier;
> - for a typedef name, is the first (or only) declaration of the identifier.

Is `function-definition` a `declaration`?

Is a `declaration` using `function-specifier` a `function-definition` or something else? ("6.7.4  Function specifiers" introduces definitions of inline functions, so it looks like  `function-definition` is `declaration`?)

In `external-declaration`, why is `function-definition` singled out instead of being included in `declaration`?

Comment: A function definition also implies a declaration (if the function isn't declared before, then the definition is also a declaration).

Answer (score 3):

A *function-definition* is not a *declaration* in the formal C grammar. This is evident from the Syntax clauses throughout the standard, which present the formal grammar.

A *function-definition* is a declaration in the sense that it does declare the identifier for a function, as well as defining the function. This is stated in C 2018 6.9 5, which says “An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an object…”

The grammar of function definitions needs to be specified separately from other declarations simply because they have a different form than other declarations. However, the tokens in the formal grammar could have been named *non-function-definition-declaration* and *function-definition-declaration* instead of *declaration* and *function-definition*. The names are of no consequence to the definition of the grammar, and the fact that *declaration* was chosen for what is actually a subset of declarations is simply an artifact of naming.

Comment: Thanks. Is a `declaration` using `function-speciﬁer` a `function-definition` or something else? "6.7.4  Function speciﬁers" introduces definitions of inline functions, so it looks like  `function-definition` is `declaration`?

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't allow functions to be defined inside a block. All function definitions must be at the top-level of a translation unit. Since the syntax for a translation unit is a sequence of external-declarations, it's logical that we'll find function definitions only in the expansion of `external-declaration`.

Of course, the top-level of a translation unit is not restricted to function definitions. It can also include declarations, including function declarations. But it cannot include (executable) statements, which in the context of the C grammar are called `statements`.

In short, the C grammar contains three mutually exclusive categories of what we might call "statement-like things":

- `statement`
- `declaration`
- `function-definition`

Block lists contain either of the first two categories; the top-level of a translation unit contains either of the second two. There's no context in which all three are acceptable.

These categories are not absolutes. Another language (or grammar) might use different wording. (In C++, declarations are statements, for example, and function definitions can occur in more contexts.)

In normal language, it's pretty common to say that a function definition is a declaration. Clearly, it declares that an identifier names a function. Even the standard occasionally uses "declaration" in this sense. But it's not in the grammatical category of `declaration`.

Similarly, a declaration is not in the grammatical category of `statement`, although in informal language, it's common to include declarations. (That's a mistake, though: declarations cannot be labelled, not even with case labels.)

Comment: Thanks. Is a `declaration` using `function-speciﬁer` a `function-definition` or something else? "6.7.4  Function speciﬁers" introduces definitions of inline functions, so it looks like  `function-definition` is `declaration`?

Comment: A `function-definition` is never a `declaration`. A `function-specifier` may appear in a `function-definition` or it may appear in a `declaration` (provided the identifier being declared is a function (6.7.4/2) other than `main` (6.7.4/4). So a `function-specifier` does not change the grammatical category. (You can use `inline` without a function body, as long as there is a definition of the function somewhere in the translation unit.)

Comment: @Tim: ^^ . Also note that GCC allows nested functions; GCC extensions don't have formal grammars so I can't say whether or not a nested function definition would be a declaration in GCC or if they consider  a function definition to be another alternative for a block list item

Comment: declarations cannot be a loop body either. C++ with its RAII would totally break there...

Comment: In  "6.7.4 Function speciﬁers"  all the examples are function definitions with `inline` or `__Noreturn`, and where are function declarations? 6.7.4 / 2 says " Function speciﬁers shall be used only in the declaration of an identiﬁer for a function.", so does that mean "A function-specifier may appear in a function-definition"?

Comment: @Tim: yes, it's uncommon to use a function-specifier without a definition but it's legal. And, yes, a function-definition declares an identifier. (This is the narrative use of "declaration", not the grammatical category.)

Comment: I edited my answer on the basis of your comment's second question

Comment: Thanks. In light of "Block lists contain either of the first two categories",  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64402335/is-a-block-a-statement

Comment: @tim: "is" and "contains" do not mean the same thing.

Comment: So "In short, the C grammar contains three mutually exclusive categories of what we might call "statement-like things": three or four? (some blocks are statements, e.g. if-statement, while  a translation unit is not any of the others)

Comment: @tim: but "block" is not a grammatical category. Nowhere in the grammar will you find a definition of it.

Answer (score 2):

> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier [ref](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p5)

The notion of declaration does not correspond exactly to the grammar symbol *declaration*. An *external-declaration* (the grammar symbol, in italics) is not necessarily a *declaration*, but an external declaration (in a Roman font) is obviously a kind of a declaration. I believe there is no other sensible interpretation of the standard.

The grammar is designed with machines (parsers) in mind, and the English text is designed for humans, so there are discrepancies here and there.

Comment: Thanks. Is a `declaration` using `function-speciﬁer` a `function-definition` or something else? "6.7.4  Function speciﬁers" introduces definitions of inline functions, so it looks like  `function-definition` is `declaration`?