# Is a block a statement?

Tags: c

In C11 standard ( I don't have the latest standard):

> 6.8  Statements and blocks
>
> A block allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped into one syntactic unit.
> The initializers of objects that have automatic storage duration, and the variable length
> array declarators of ordinary identiﬁers with block scope, are evaluated and the values are
> stored  in  the  objects  (including  storing  an  indeterminate  value  in  objects  without  an
> initializer) each time the declaration is reached in the order of execution, as if it were a
> statement, and within each declaration in the order that declarators appear.

Is a block a statement?

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, yes. In its simplest interpretation, if we look at the grammar production before your quote. The most obvious block is a compound statement.

> ```
> statement:
>        labeled-statement
>        compound-statement
>        expression-statement
>        selection-statement
>        iteration-statement
>        jump-statement
> ```

The production of `compound-statement` describes blocks. And even says this explicitly in a paragraph following that

> **6.8.2 Compound statement**
>
> ```
> compound-statement:
>      { block-item-list }
> block-item-list:
>        block-item
>        block-item-list block-item
> block-item:
>        declaration
>        statement
> ```
>
> 2 A compound statement is a block.

And other statements in the following sections are also designated as blocks. For instance

> **6.8.4 Selection statements**
>
> 3 A selection statement is a block whose scope is a strict subset of
> the scope of its enclosing block. Each associated substatement is also
> a block whose scope is a strict subset of the scope of the selection
> statement.

Nothing except the statements described in 6.8 is ever called a block. So blocks are always a statement of some sort. The rule of thumb is that a statement with `{ }` always means a block.

Comment: The function body is a block, but it is not a statement. `if`, `while` and `for` are blocks without `{ }`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - The grammar production for a function definition uses the `compound-statement` element. So "not a statement" in what sense? Of not using the more general "statement" grammar element? It is a specific sort of statement.

Answer (score 0):

From wikibooks,

> A block is a program region containing definitions of variables and that delimits the regions where these definitions apply. In C programming language, a block is created using a pair of curly braces. The beginning of the block is denoted by an open curly brace '{' and the end is denoted by a closing curly brace '}'. The block collects statements together into a single compound statements.

The C code bellow shows a block where the block is used only to define a scope of a variable and it is not a statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n = 1;
  {
    int n = 2;
    printf("%d\n", n);
  }
  printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

**EDIT:**
As already mentioned I have made a mistake saying that block is not always a statement but the correct answer is that block is **ALWAYS** a statement.

Comment: Nope, a block is *always* a statement, and your reference seems to agree.  Also, when you quote an external resource, be sure to provide a full citation to the source. "From wikibooks" is not sufficient. A URL, preferably in the form of a hyperlink, should be provided to designate at least the document from which the quotation was drawn, and more specific identification is appreciated where that is available.

Comment: Ok,thanks for the comment I have misunderstood the source I would edit my post.